# Make a list from two lists

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two lists that contain the same Elements as well as different elements. How to make a list from these two lists and spring me commonalities and new items?

```
...
            <list-of-items items="application.units"
                           label="$item.name"
                           selected-item="unit"
                           selectable="true"
                           onedit="on_edit_unit($item)"
                           editable="false"
                           size="small">
            </list-of-items>
            <list-of-items items="applicationCible.units"
                           label="$item.name"
                           selected-item="unit"
                           selectable="true"
                           onedit="on_edit_unit($item)"
                           editable="false"
                           size="small">
            </list-of-items>
...
```

### Update

**In my HTML:**

```
..
          <list-of-items items="platforms.concat(platformsCible).unique()"
                           label="$item"
                           selected-item="platform"
                           createfunction="add_platform($name)"
                           selectable="true"
                           editable="false"
                           size="small">
            </list-of-items>
..
```

**In my JS:**

```
propertiesModule.controller('PropertiesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'PropertiesService', 'ApplicationService', 'PlatformService', 'Page',  function ($scope, $routeParams, PropertiesService, ApplicationService, PlatformService, Page) {

...

Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var a = this.concat();
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
            if(a[i] === a[j])
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }

    return a;
};

}]);
```

There is duplicate item with this method

Comment: do yo want to merge them?

Comment: @MajoB yes exactly i want to merge them

Comment: you can use application.units.concat(applicationCible.units)

Comment: @MajoB very well thx post the solution

Comment: @MajoB so can i concatenate without duplicates in my list .?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64324/discussion-between-mercer-and-majob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to concatenate the two lists using [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
<list-of-items items="application.units.concat(applicationCible.units)"
               label="$item.name"
               selected-item="unit"
               selectable="true"
               onedit="on_edit_unit($item)"
               editable="false"
               size="small">
</list-of-items>
```

Comment: so can i concatenate without duplicates in my list .?